# Ruby Rails and Webscraping (Nokogiri) and Nitrous.io

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri

Can I use Rails and Nokogiri?

I tried this thread and have the same problem but the solutions dont work for me:
[Cannot require 'nokogiri' in Rails (but works in irb)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6082305/cannot-require-nokogiri-in-rails-but-works-in-irb)

```
 class IndexController < ApplicationController
 require 'nokogiri'
    require 'open-uri'
  def index
    @name = "Help"


    end

end
```

Error I get is:

```
cannot load such file -- nokogiri
```

I am running this in nitrous.io. I did a list of gems using:

```
 <li>Ruby: <%=RUBY_VERSION%></li>
 <li>Gems: <%=`gem list`%></li>
```

Which gets me

```
    Ruby: 2.0.0
Gems: actionmailer (4.0.0) actionpack (4.0.0) activemodel (4.0.0) activerecord (4.0.0) activerecord-deprecated_finders (1.0.3) activesupport (4.0.0) arel (4.0.0) atomic (1.1.14) builder (3.1.4) bundler (1.3.5) coffee-rails (4.0.0) coffee-script (2.2.0) coffee-script-source (1.6.3) erubis (2.7.0) execjs (2.0.1) hike (1.2.3) i18n (0.6.5) jbuilder (1.5.1) jquery-rails (3.0.4) json (1.8.0) mail (2.5.4) mime-types (1.25) minitest (4.7.5) multi_json (1.8.0) polyglot (0.3.3) rack (1.5.2) rack-test (0.6.2) rails (4.0.0) railties (4.0.0) rake (10.1.0) rdoc (3.12.2) sass (3.2.10) sass-rails (4.0.0) sdoc (0.3.20) sprockets (2.10.0) sprockets-rails (2.0.0) sqlite3 (1.3.8) thor (0.18.1) thread_safe (0.1.3) tilt (1.4.1) treetop (1.4.15) turbolinks (1.3.0) tzinfo (0.3.37) uglifier (2.2.1)
```

Nokogiri is not here even though I have run a gem install nokogiri.

Comment: do you have it in your gemfile?

Comment: This is a duplicate of the post you mentioned [Cannot require 'nokogiri' in Rails (but works in irb)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6082305/cannot-require-nokogiri-in-rails-but-works-in-irb), because you don't seem to be using bundler which was the answer to that question, and to yours.

Comment: I didnt feel it was quite the same hence my post. I didnt really understand the require and the gem file. I did use a gem install and a bundle install. I didnt necessarily understand the bundler thing. Just blindly wandering through trying to understand whilst doing something mildly interesting :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `nokogiri` to your gem file, run `bundle install` and start using it. There is no need for `require`

After bundle install, you can straight away use it in controller actions. e.g

```
def index
 p = Nokogori::HTML(open('http://domain.com')) #=> p now have the contents of the page
end
```

Comment: Thank You. I dont necessarily understand but you are correct and I didn't need a bundle install fyi.