# Rails Cannot require 'nokogiri/nokogiri', though IRB can

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, nokogiri

First of all, despite our nearly identical titles, this problem is not solved by [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6082305/cannot-require-nokogiri-in-rails-but-works-in-irb).

Two days ago I ran rails in dev mode and everything was fine. Today I start up the server and I am met with the following error:

```
/Users/martin/Desktop/hotline/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/nokogiri-1.8.1/lib/nokogiri.rb:33:in `require': cannot load such file -- nokogiri/nokogiri (LoadError)
from /Users/martin/Desktop/hotline/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/nokogiri-1.8.1/lib/nokogiri.rb:33:in `rescue in <top (required)>'
from /Users/martin/Desktop/hotline/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/nokogiri-1.8.1/lib/nokogiri.rb:29:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/martin/Desktop/hotline/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/loofah-2.1.1/lib/loofah.rb:3:in `require'
from /Users/martin/Desktop/hotline/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/loofah-2.1.1/lib/loofah.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/martin/Desktop/hotline/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rails-html-sanitizer-1.0.3/lib/rails-html-sanitizer.rb:2:in `require'
from /Users/martin/Desktop/hotline/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rails-html-sanitizer-1.0.3/lib/rails-html-sanitizer.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/martin/Desktop/hotline/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/actionview-5.1.4/lib/action_view/helpers/sanitize_helper.rb:2:in `require'
from /Users/martin/Desktop/hotline/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/actionview-5.1.4/lib/action_view/helpers/sanitize_helper.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/martin/Desktop/hotline/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/actionview-5.1.4/lib/action_view/helpers.rb:58:in `require'
from /Users/martin/Desktop/hotline/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/actionview-5.1.4/lib/action_view/helpers.rb:58:in `<module:Helpers>'
from /Users/martin/Desktop/hotline/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/actionview-5.1.4/lib/action_view/helpers.rb:4:in `<module:ActionView>'
from /Users/martin/Desktop/hotline/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/actionview-5.1.4/lib/action_view/helpers.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/martin/Desktop/hotline/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-rails-3.2.1/lib/sprockets/rails/context.rb:1:in `require'
from /Users/martin/Desktop/hotline/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-rails-3.2.1/lib/sprockets/rails/context.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/martin/Desktop/hotline/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-rails-3.2.1/lib/sprockets/railtie.rb:7:in `require'
from /Users/martin/Desktop/hotline/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-rails-3.2.1/lib/sprockets/railtie.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/martin/Desktop/hotline/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sass-rails-5.0.6/lib/sass/rails/railtie.rb:3:in `require'
from /Users/martin/Desktop/hotline/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sass-rails-5.0.6/lib/sass/rails/railtie.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/martin/Desktop/hotline/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sass-rails-5.0.6/lib/sass/rails.rb:11:in `require'
from /Users/martin/Desktop/hotline/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sass-rails-5.0.6/lib/sass/rails.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/martin/Desktop/hotline/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sass-rails-5.0.6/lib/sass-rails.rb:1:in `require'
from /Users/martin/Desktop/hotline/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sass-rails-5.0.6/lib/sass-rails.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/martin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:81:in `require'
from /Users/martin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:81:in `block (2 levels) in require'
from /Users/martin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `each'
from /Users/martin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block in require'
from /Users/martin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:65:in `each'
from /Users/martin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:65:in `require'
from /Users/martin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler.rb:114:in `require'
from /Users/martin/Desktop/hotline/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/martin/Desktop/hotline/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:133:in `require'
from /Users/martin/Desktop/hotline/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:133:in `block in perform'
from /Users/martin/Desktop/hotline/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:130:in `tap'
from /Users/martin/Desktop/hotline/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:130:in `perform'
from /Users/martin/Desktop/hotline/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
from /Users/martin/Desktop/hotline/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
from /Users/martin/Desktop/hotline/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor.rb:387:in `dispatch'
from /Users/martin/Desktop/hotline/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/command/base.rb:63:in `perform'
from /Users/martin/Desktop/hotline/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/command.rb:44:in `invoke'
from /Users/martin/Desktop/hotline/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/commands.rb:16:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/martin/Desktop/hotline/bin/rails:9:in `require'
from /Users/martin/Desktop/hotline/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/martin/Desktop/hotline/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
from /Users/martin/Desktop/hotline/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
from /Users/martin/Desktop/hotline/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
from /Users/martin/Desktop/hotline/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in `run'
from /Users/martin/Desktop/hotline/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/martin/Desktop/hotline/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:31:in `load'
from /Users/martin/Desktop/hotline/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:31:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/martin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:70:in `require'
from /Users/martin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:70:in `require'
from /Users/martin/Desktop/hotline/bin/spring:15:in `<top (required)>'
from bin/rails:3:in `load'
from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
```

Which I have summized to mean that when rails calls `require 'nokogiri/nokogiri' the rails cannot find the gem and it fails. My first thought was to check and see if I even had the gem, so I called

```
>>irb
2.4.1 :001 > require 'nokogiri/nokogiri'
 => true
```

My next thought was to reload nokogiri, so I uninstall and reinstalled a handful a times and restarted my Mac, to no avail.

I searched online for a spell and the closest person I found to having my same problem's solution was that there was a compatiablity issue with Windows. That's super unhelpful because I have a Mac.

Right now, I don't even know what I don't know. Why is this error firing? What changed on my computer since now and two days ago to make this error? What do I need to do to fix this problem?

Comment: in your `irb`, what does the `RUBY_VERSION ` constant return?

Comment: `RUBY_VERSION` returns `=> "2.4.1"`

Comment: when you install a gem — either by `gem install` or using `bundle` — it's specific to that Ruby environment. Your Rails app is bundled for 2.4.0 and Nokogiri is installed for 2.4.1. Set your Ruby env to the correct version and run `bundle install` again, restart your Rails server, and you should be set.

Answer (score 0):

*sigh* 
I found the problem. If you keep your most recent projects on the desktop, like I do, Mac OS will try to save space on your disk by uploading files to the cloud. If half your app is in the cloud, when you try to run your localhost, half your app won't be there. I redownloaded the file from the cloud and it ran perfectly.